# Django global variable for all templates or context processor manipulation

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a website with 2 different languages.

Text which should be translated is only in the template.htmls (index.html, accounts.html ... about 20 files)

sometemplate.html

```
...
    <div>{% if ls == 'at' %}Deutschtext {% else %}english text{% endif %}</div>
...
```

my context processor

```
...
    def language_selection(request):
        return {'ls': 'at'}
...
```

This works, but how can I change the value of the context_processor from template?

Or is there any other approach for a 'global variable' which can be changed and is accessible from all templates?

Comment: You shouldn't be modifying variables from the template. What context is the variable going to change in? If it depends on the request, then you have the request available to the context processor and can set the right value at that point.

Comment: I don't understand. The variable should be availible in all templates. How can I send a parameter with a request? or how can I call the context processor from a path/view and fix the value until I call the specific path again?

Comment: i advice you to use a view for changing the language and after that store the result in a session and use that session in the templates

Comment: A global variable to update the language and translate the content... With Django... Isn't it already invented?

Comment: @ Thierno Amadou Sow if you have a link which show the session part it would be nice, otherwise don't mind, i'll check your tip sound promising.

Comment: @Tonio, question or fact?

Comment: Fact. Why don't use the standard django i18n support? Current language are accessible in python code and templates, and you can translate the strings easy.

Comment: @Tonio, cause every tutorial goes like this install package 1, do this, than than etc. I tried it for over 2 hours and get the failure install GNU gettrext or sth. in my humble opionion I18 and N10 has a massive overhead if you only use 2 languages and translate only in template, but if you know a resource, where is a simple example without any installation of po.files generatin stuff, please let me know.